# Although I created the route correctly But when I try to show the page It gives me an error page not found

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, controller

**This is my function in MemberController**

```
public function text(){
    return "hello";
}
```

**This is my route**

```
Route::get('/text',[MemberController::class,'text']);
```

So,basically its unable to read new route that i created.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO ... make sure your routes are not cached: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Do you access this route via link or ajax call?
Do you have any other routes that do work?

Comment: try `php artisan route:list` and check if the route is registered and you are hitting the correct url (possibly it's `api/text`)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you're using laravel 8 and above
follwoing should be your controller code (MemberController.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MemberController extends Controller{
   
    public function text(){
       return "hello";
    }
}
```

and this should be your route code (web.php)

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\MemberController;

Route::get('/text',[MemberController::class,'text']);
```

Comment: You should uppercase Controller in your MemberController class, most likely.

Comment: yes you're right, i have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Code you have provided is not enough, though you can check following things.

1. See if your routes aren't cached. Run `php artisan route:clear` in order to clear the cached routes.
2. Where have you defined the route? If it's in the `web.php` file then, your actual url should be: http://localhost:8000/text.
3. If it's in the `api.php` file then, your url should be: http://localhost:8000/api/text.